# MySql com entity framework Code First ID pulando 10

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, code-first, microsoft-azure

Estou configurando um *MySql* no *Azure* para uma aplicação que estou trabalhando, no entanto ao salvar meus registros a `identity column` está se incrementando de 10 em 10.

Isso seria uma configuração ajustável pelo entity ou um ajuste feito para todas as tabelas diretamente no banco de dados?

No caso, o que e como eu deveria mudar essa opção para que se auto incremente apenas 1?

Comment: Resolvido o problema?

Comment: Azure não possui serviço de MySQL, ele é terceirizado por uma empresa chamada ClearDB, e no plano gratuito deles, apenas ofertam instalação default e medium-thrust. Então, se quiser usar gratuito, não há muito o que fazer. Porém, vc pode subir uma VM pequena, instalar MySQL nela e usar como seu database server e configurar como quiser.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma variável que controla isso: `autoincrement`

Vê se consegue identificar o valor dela assim:

```html
SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='the_table_you_want';
```

Para mudar seria assim:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

[Olha esse aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why)